# Missing Required Parameters for Route in Laravel error

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am working with Laravel in this route :

```
Route::get('turnIn/{turnin}',"TurninController@index")->name('turnin.index');
```

and when calling the route :

```
{{ route('turnin.index', [$turnin])}}
```

Shows an error **Missing required parameters for [Route: turnin.index] [URI: turnIn/{turnin}].**

Comment: would be `{{ route('turnin.index', $turnin) }}` or `{{ route('turnin.index', ['turnin' => $turnin]) }}`

Comment: you should make sure `$turnin` isn't `null`

Comment: I can see the object when I remove the route('')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I was passing an array of objects instead of a single one "Turnin" this is why the route wasn't accepting the parameters

Answer (score 1):

Would be :

```
{{ route('turnin.index', $turnin) }}
```

Or,

```
{{ route('turnin.index', ['turnin' => $turnin]) }}
```